# Do history majors at Ukrainian universities typically have to do archaeological field work?

Tags: ukrainian-language, voroshilovgrad, serhiy-zhadan

In *Voroshilovgrad*, when Herman and Ernst met at the airport at the first time, they had the following discussion:

> "... What'd you major in?"
> "History."
> At this, his expression changed completely...
> "You know, Herman... I majored in history too. I just fell into the job at the airport. Where'd you get your degre?"
> "Kharkiv."
> "History major?"
> "History major."
> **"Where'd you do your field work?"**
> "**The usual**, just outside the city."
> "Digging?"
> "Digging."

I'm slightly confused by this exchange.

My first thought was that "Kharkiv" referred to the V. N. Karzin Karkiv National University, which is a large public university in Karkiv, Ukraine. They do, in fact, have a School of History as well as a [history museum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kharkiv_University_History_Museum), which evidently includes a Museum of Archaeology. According to their [web site](https://karazin.ua/en/fakulteti-ta-instituti/istorichnii-fakultet/),

> In total, the School students are taught more than 150 courses and specialty courses, covering the topics from the history of ancient civilizations to modern problems of European integration and international relations. The basic courses taught at the School of History include: History of Primitive Society, Archeology, Ethnology, History of the Ancient East, History of Ancient Greece and Rome, History of the Middle Ages, History of Western Europe and North America of Modern Times, History of Ukraine, History of Russia, Special Historical Disciplines, Historical Geography, Fundamentals of Historiography, Historiography of the History of Ukraine, etc.

It goes on to state that "Students undergo practical training at the University History Museum and the only Ukrainian university-based Museum of Archeology."

On the other hand, the author of the book attended the H.S. Skovoroda Kharkiv National Pedagogical University (which I have not been able to ascertain whether they are affiliated beyond just being in the same city). According to their [history department web site](http://hnpu.edu.ua/en/division/faculty-history),

> These departments employ recognized specialists in the specialty, including 10 doctors of sciences and professors, 30 PhD and docent. **The structure of the faculty also includes an archeological laboratory, which collects unique artifacts found by students during research expeditions** and two centers focused on close cooperation with schools in Kharkiv and other areas: methods of teaching history and social sciences and the center of school local lore. The conferences organized by this center often invite the most famous national methodologists in history and law, as well as regional historians from all over Ukraine.

Which of these universities did the author have in mind here, and what is the exact relationship between them? Also, is it normal for history majors in Ukraine to include field work of some kind? Is this normally some kind of archaeology, or can it include other things too? How are these programs normally structured?

Which archeological sites exist near Kharkiv?